# Angular 4 integration with CakePhp

Tags: angular, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I've been using cake for a while and, on a new project, I'd like to use Angular 4 to manage my front-end.
I'm new to Angular and I can't figure out how to merge Cake and Angular to make if work.

I guess I should use Cake's layout and load < my-app > into it. But how to load Angular and the app's content?

I'm stuck and some help would be appreciated.
Thanks, Antonio

Comment: The fact is that I don't really know how to get startet.
I have created my Cake project,
I've added Angular content in webroot/js/MyApp/ and I am trying to load the content of my Angular app into a page.

Answer (score -1):

To get started you can follow these simple things:

1. Modify and add `data-ng-app` in to the body tag (look for default.ctp). I would suggest to add angular controller name as cakephp controller name.
   For example if I visit url `<root>/mysite/users`, I would edit the user's view template (templates/users/index.ctp etc) with `data-ng-controller='Users'` (modifying the cake bake templates).
2. Javascript files containing angular code can be stored in webroot and enqueued to the document.
3. (optional) Enable JSON extensions and work out with output
4. In the cake controller handle the request and interact with database.

This [link](https://medium.com/@ranostaj/login-with-cakephp3-and-angularjs-b4b124708086) could help you for getting an example although not for angular4.

Comment: Which are the Javascript files containing angular code that I need to load? Where are they located?

Comment: You will need to get angular js and link it. And you custom code like app.js controller.js would be in webroot/js folder...

Comment: Vishal, do you mean _angular.js_? Like the one I can find in Google CDN (https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#angularjs)?
If so, you are refering to AngularJS, the version **1** (or 1.6.4) of the framework. I'm talking about **Angular 4**.
On Angular **4**, I can't find the javascript file(s) to link to.